# multiple field search form displaying entire database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I am trying to create a database with multiple fields for searching but it is displaying the entire database if there is an empty field. i suspect it is because of the OR's in the query and i am not sure how to fix it.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{ 
$con = mysqli_connect();
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$maiden = $_POST['maiden'];
$birth = $_POST['birth'];
$death = $_POST['death'];
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM obits WHERE  surname LIKE '%" . $surname . "%' OR firstname LIKE '%" . $firstname  . "%' OR maiden LIKE '%" . $maiden . "%'  OR birth LIKE '%" . $birth . "%' OR death LIKE '%" . $death . "%' OR obittext LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

further down i have this:

```
if (isset($result) && $result->num_rows > 0);
```

then follows the table etc. i think i have all the pertinent info here. any suggestions? please use english rather than programmer, i am quite new at this. thanks in advance!

Comment: "please use english rather than programmer,"  - that part got me LoL, umm. Back to business. Not sure what you mean by "display the entire database - but Yes, due to the large amount of `ORs` in your `Query` and doing `Wildcard` searches on each columns, it will yield alot of results.

Comment: it displays every entry in the database if there is a blank field

Comment: Why dont you validate the values prior to sending it to the query?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at one of the conditions:

```
surname LIKE '%" . $surname . "%'
```

Assuming, `$surname` is `Miller` here, you select all rows that have a surname like `%Miller%`. The `%` signs are wildcards, which can basically stand for *anything*. This means you are selecting all rows where the surname contains `Miller` with any string before or after it, including empty ones.

Now, if `Miller` would be empty in this case, you are looking for `%%`, so an empty string with anything before or after it -- so really any possible string. As a result, every row will be selected.

Since this is true not only for the surname, but for any of the columns, leaving any of the criteria blank will result in all rows being selected.

[Find more info on SQL Wildcards.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)

To **skip empty values in your where clause**, you can build it dynamically:

```
$condition = "WHERE";

if(!empty($surname)){
    $condition .= "surname LIKE '$surname' OR";
}

if(!empty($firstname)){
    $condition .= "firstname LIKE '$firstname' OR";
}

// ...

$sql = "SELECT * FROM obits " . $condition;
```

Note:

- There will be a trailing `OR` in the condition that you will have to remove.
- If all conditions are blank, this will also lead to an error.

But it should give you an inpiration! :-)

**Side Note:**
You should look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Passing POST variables directly into an SQL statement is [highly dangerous](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: okay that makes sense, how might i go about fixing this?

Comment: well let me be more specific. i want a bit of a buffer for misspellings which is why i thought LIKE might be the way to go. if it's causing this problem how would i fix it while still having a little bit of a buffer for misspellings?

Comment: Just check for the empty values in the posted data. if its not empty then run the query. otherwise dont run.

Comment: @aloeveraking24 - He's basically telling you to check to ensure that all values being passed to the `Query` are not `Empty`

Comment: again, new at this. is there a tutorial somewhere for how to only run if not empty?

Comment: my limited knowledge results in the following: WHERE surname LIKE '%" . $surname . "%' AND NOT NULL

Comment: I edited my answer -- this should give you a starting point!